# Trying to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql

So I am wamp and I am trying to connect to phpmyAdmin, and I am doing this by going into

Wamp>www>project

Once I am inside my folder, and I have created a file titled index.php and inside the text editor
I have written:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

but then I try to run it, and all I see in the web browser is the actual code printed to the screen. It should appear blank showing that it has connected, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your apache server is not set up to recognize PHP files? I thought WAMP would set that up automatically though? What URL are using to view this page?

Comment: file:///C:/wamp/www/proj/index.php

Comment: Looks like you're viewing the file directly and not from WAMP. You need to use a url like `http://localhost:8000/proj/` to view from your WAMP server. I can't remember what the default port for WAMP is, so you'll need to figure that out.

Comment: It may just be port 80. So try going to `http://localhost/proj` Source: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Abdul, I posted my comment as an answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're viewing the file `index.php` directly and not from your WAMP server. This is why you see your code displayed in plain text.

The default port for your WAMP server should be port 80. You should be able to view your `index.php` page correctly from: `http://localhost/proj`.